# Add a new row to an existing dataframe pandas error

Tags: python, pandas

I need to append a new row that I specify to an existing dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(42)
data = {'group':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c' ],
        'value' : [1, 2, 5,  3, 4, 5, 7, 4, 7, 9],
        'year': ['2010', '2010', '2010', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2012', '2012','2012', ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The new row is:

```
new_row={'group': 'the current group', 'year': 'current year','value':''}
```

so the data looks like this:

```
    group   value   year
0   a   1   2010
1   a   2   2010
2   a   5   2010
3   a       2010
0   b   3   2011
1   b   4   2011
2   b   5   2011
3   b   7   2011
4   b       2011
0   c   4   2012
1   c   7   2012
2   c   9   2012
3   c       2012
```

I have tried:

```
new_row={'value':''}
df2 = df.groupby(df['group'])
df = pd.concat([i.append(new_row, ignore_index=True) for _, i in df2])
df
```

but i get the following error:

```
    FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  df = pd.concat([i.append(new_row, ignore_index=True) for _, i in df2])
```

I havent figured out how to do it without append. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason why append is not working for you?

Comment: append was removed as of pandas 2.0 @JacksonDunn

Comment: Thanks, still using old pandas. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `append` with `pd.concat` an one row dataframe. Then forward fill the empty value.

```py
out = (pd.concat([pd.concat([group, pd.DataFrame([{'value':''}])], ignore_index=True)
                 for _, group in df.groupby('group')])
       .ffill())
```

```
print(out)

  group value  year
0     a     1  2010
1     a     2  2010
2     a     5  2010
3     a        2010
0     b     3  2011
1     b     4  2011
2     b     5  2011
3     b     7  2011
4     b        2011
0     c     4  2012
1     c     7  2012
2     c     9  2012
3     c        2012
```

Or with `df.groupby.apply`

```py
out = (df.groupby('group', group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g, pd.DataFrame([{'value': ''}])], ignore_index=True))
       .ffill())
```

Or if you want to make your target row more customizable, you can try to create the dict like `dict(g.iloc[0], **{'value': ''})`

```
out = (df.groupby('group', group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g,
                                   pd.DataFrame([dict(g.iloc[0], **{'value': ''})])],
                                  ignore_index=True)))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the concat method which is super simple.

```
new_row = pd.DataFrame({"group": ["your value"], "value": [your value], "year": [your value]})

df = pd.concat([df, new_row], ignore_index=True)
```

You shouldn't need to include the append call at all.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DF from the `new_row` dict and concat it with your original df.

```
data = {'group':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c' ],
        'value' : [1, 2, 5,  3, 4, 5, 7, 4, 7, 9],
        'year': ['2010', '2010', '2010', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2012', '2012','2012', ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
new_row={'group': 'the current group', 'year': 'current year','value':''}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
               group value          year
0                  a     1          2010
1                  a     2          2010
2                  a     5          2010
3                  b     3          2011
4                  b     4          2011
5                  b     5          2011
6                  b     7          2011
7                  c     4          2012
8                  c     7          2012
9                  c     9          2012
10  the current group        current year
```

Comment: I need to add the new row after each group. The answer below helped but thanks regardless!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns `group` and `year` forms what you call *group*, you can use :

```
cols = ["group", "year"]

def subheader(g):
    new_row = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(cols, g.name), value="")])
    return pd.concat([g, new_row], ignore_index=True)

out = df.groupby(cols, sort=False, group_keys=False).apply(subheader)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  group value  year
0     a     1  2010
1     a     2  2010
2     a     5  2010
3     a        2010
0     b     3  2011
1     b     4  2011
2     b     5  2011
3     b     7  2011
4     b        2011
0     c     4  2012
1     c     7  2012
2     c     9  2012
3     c        2012
```